# c# select single node xpath returns null

Tags: c#, xpath

I have an app config in a c# project I need to edit at run time.  As part of this I have a custom section collection I need to select a single node for. This is the xml and selection statement from my immediate window:

```
node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Customers/add[@id='1']");
```

null

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="customers" type ="ImporterSupport.CustConfigSection, ImporterSupport"/>
    </configSections>
    <customers>
        <add id ="1" license="gh620g0g0g0g0g3p" ServerAddress ="localhost"  ServerPort="8292" SettingsFile ="AutoImportTest.txt" Confirm ="false" DisableRemoveRecips="true" DisableRecoverRecips="true" DisableAlphaId ="true" />
    </customers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xml is case sensitive. Use

```
var node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//customers/add[@id='1']");
```